# Buffer overflows: writing 7 in hexadecimal without 'null terminator' (0x00)

Tags: c, hex, buffer-overflow

I'm trying to exploit a buffer overflow vulnerability to overwrite the return address of the stack.

However the code I'm trying to 'hack' makes use canary system. It initializes an integer always to the same hard coded value, 7, and checks to see later if that variable is still the same.

I can create a buffer overflow, and I can write over this variable, however I am having trouble writing the correct value. The buffer overflow is caused by the incorrect use of strcpy. The input is given through the contents of a file, shown below:

```
0000000: 6132 3334 3536 3738 395f 6232 3334 3536  a23456789_b23456
0000010: 3738 3907 00                             789..
```

The last 2 hexadecimal values (07 00) is where I'm having trouble. 07 is the value I'm trying to place in the variable (it gets placed in the correct memory position). However I believe I need to write 00 in the next position, otherwise the variable takes on a larger value than 7.

The problem with 00, is that it is acting as a null terminator for strcpy, which means I can't supply anymore information after it, and thus can't overwrite the return address.

Is this situation possible to overcome, or is it just impossible to supply the correct value without the use of 0x00 ?

EDIT:

The code (mostly abbreviated to the point):

```
void getwd(char *path)
{
  strcpy( path, mapped_path );
  return path;
}

void pwd(void)
{

  int canary = 7;
  char path[MAXPATHLEN + 1];

  if (getwd(path) == (char *) NULL)
  {
    printf("Couldn't get current directory!\n");
  }
  else
  {
    printf("Current directory = %s\n", path);
    printf("max strlen(path) is %d, strlen(path) = %d\n", MAXPATHLEN-1, strlen(path));
    printf("Canary should be 7.  Canary = %d\n", canary);
    if (canary != 7)
      printf("ALERT: path[MAXPATHLEN + 1] has been overflowed!\n");
  }
}
```

The buffer overflow is happening in getwd, where mapped_path is larger than path. mapped_path at that point can hold whatever values you want.

Comment: It *might* be possible, but it's hard to say without seeing any code.

Comment: I've added the code in question. Could you take a look at it again ?

Comment: Well, as it is, the checking of `canary` is strictly informational, so you could still overwrite the return address.  You'll just get that *ALERT* print when you do.

Comment: Yes, I realize that, this is a purely academical exercise. I'm just trying to go a bit beyond what was asked (triggering the canary). I do however realize it is probably impossible using just this one exploit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to inject actual shellcode, that programmatically inserts the integer 7 at this specific position.

First step is to find the return address and set this to a particular position in the buffer.

Second step is to place a zero-free shellcode at the predefined position and let the shellcode set the variable to 7 again.

Zero-free shellcode is not hard to write, because of the many possible ways to zero out a variable without using the actual digit like `xor eax, eax` (if you are familiar with assembly).

If you have never done this before, it would probably take much time to achieve this goal.

Comment: I have glossed over things like 'xor eax, eax' and I mostly understand what it is you are explaining. But after I have all of that in the buffer how do I execute it without changing the %esp and waiting for the function to return ?

Comment: You would have to change the esp and the return address to let the EIP (instruction pointer) jump to your shellcode.

Comment: He's going to have a problem if it's a non-executable stack. Hard to do ROP code when the program aborts before returning.

Comment: There are still ways to do it, but ASLR and NONEXE space won't make it easier for sure.